# iptables what does dpt:route mean?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, dd-wrt

I am seeing these lines when I list like `iptables -v -L`

```
pkts bytes target   prot opt in     out     source               destination
 0     0 DROP       udp  --  vlan2  any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route
 0     0 DROP       udp  --  br0    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route
 0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:route
```

This seems a bit contradictory to mean because it seems like it is accepting and dropping at the same. The last rule also seems a bit unsafe to me but it was there on the default installation on DD-WRT so I don't think I'm understanding what it's there for in the first place. I couldn't find any documentation on what dpt:route means. Thanks for any clarifications

Comment: The format of the last column is `dpt:<protocol>` where `protocol` is the human readable name of a service/port number (e.g. `22` will be shown as `ssh`.). Port `520` corresponds to `route` and is used for RIP (Routing Information Protocol).

Comment: Forgot to say that `dpt` means "destination port". So each of those rules means packets destined for the RIP service.

Answer (score 2):

`dpt:route` means match packets with the destination port associated with the `route` service. To map a service to a port number take a look at `/etc/services`. From that we get:

```
$ cat /etc/services | grep route
route           520/udp         router routed   # RIP
```

> This seems a bit contradictory to mean because it seems like it is accepting and dropping at the same.

The rules are not contradictory because they have one key difference - the input interface: `vlan2`, `br0` and `any` for each of the respective rules. So taken together the rules are saying to drop all RIP packets that arrive from `vlan2` and `br0` but accept RIP packets that arrive from all other interfaces.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense to me. I read the Wikipedia on RIP and I see it's very important to how routers function. My follow up is, is this the normal (and safe) way that these rules are setup? Because at first I thought it was accepting from the outside WAN, but since it is dropping br0 is it correct to assume it's not accepting from the outside? I assume it's right since I think it was the default setting

Comment: Firstly, are you actually running a router? If not, RIP should not be accepted at all. I don't know how you have set up  your `br0` and `vlan2` but those are typically for LAN interfaces. So the rules actually block RIP packets from inside the LAN and allow RIP packets from all other interfaces which presumably includes outside/WAN interfaces. And that makes sense because RIP is a routing protocol and such packets are WAN side and not LAN side.

Comment: Yep I saw this on my router running the dd-wrt firmware. I didn't realize that it's supposed to be this way. Now I know better, thank you